# Magento Custom Widget Issues

Tags: magento

I hope someone can help me out here.

I'm currently developing a Magento widget that pulls through a list of sub-categories and the products contained in those categories and renders them in an ul.

I'm having two issues so far.

1. The HTML from the .phtml template doesn't get rendered on the frontend

I've got it to the stage where by the widget shows in the backend and when you select it, it does insert the widget pointing to the correct path for the template but when you check the frontend it doesn't render anything. I'm unsure as to why? My code is below.

1. The product names do not pull through

I've tested my PHP code from the .phtml template file on the front end and it works to an extent. It renders several  tags each with a category link and then underneath a list of the correct products for that category. Each product is a link and it has the correct URL for that product but it doesn't seem to be pulling through the product names using:

```
<?php echo $_product->getName()?>
```

Below is my code, with the paths to the files.

**template/catalog/navigation/pronav_list.phtml**

```
<?php
    $mainCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load(3) -> getChildren();
    $categoryIDs = explode(',', $mainCategory);
?>
<?php foreach($categoryIDs as $catID): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load($catID); ?>
        <a href="<?php  echo $category -> getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php  echo $category -> getName(); ?>"><?php  echo $category -> getName(); ?></a>
        <?php  $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') -> addCategoryFilter($category); ?>
        <?php if(count($_productCollection)>0): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName()?>"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php  endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php  endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach?>
```

**app/code/local/Ecreation/PNListWidget/Block**

```
<?php
    class Ecreation_PNListWidget_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface {

        protected function _construct() {
         parent::_construct();
        }

        protected function _toHtml() {
            $blockHTML = $this -> getLayout() -> createBlock('cms/block') -> toHtml();

            return parent::_toHtml();
        }

    }
?>
```

**app/code/local/Ecreation/PNListWidget/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ecreation_PNListWidget>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ecreation_PNListWidget>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ecreation/PNListWidget/etc/widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <list type="pronav/list_widget">
        <name>ProNav Navigation List Widget</name>
        <description>Automatically renders 2nd level categories and their products.</description>
        <parameters>
            <template>
                <required>1</required>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <label>Template</label>
                <type>select</type>
                <values>
                    <nav_list translate="label">
                        <value>catalog/navigation/pronav_list.phtml</value>
                        <label>ProNav Navigation List</label>
                    </nav_list>
                </values>
            </template>
        </parameters>
    </list>
</widgets>
```

I hope I've been as detailed as possible and that someone is able to point me in the right direction.

NOTE: Eventually what I'd like the widget to do is allow the user to select a top level category, then get the ID for that category and insert it in to the code to be used as the main category in the below code where it loads the category ID 3:

```
$mainCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load(3) -> getChildren();
```

**EDIT**: OK guys I've modified the .phtml file code to now show products names, as well as only show the products that have been set to visible in the catalog. Code below.

```
<?php
$mainCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load(3) -> getChildren();
$categoryIDs = explode(',', $mainCategory);
?>

<div class="row">
    <?php foreach($categoryIDs as $catID): ?>
        <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load($catID);?>
        <?php $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') -> addAttributeToSelect(array('name','visibility'), 'inner') -> addCategoryFilter($category); ?>

        <?php if(count($_productCollection)>0): ?>
            <ul>
                <a href="<?php  echo $category -> getUrl();?>" title="<?php   echo $category -> getName();?>"><?php   echo $category -> getName(); ?></a>
                <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                    <?php $productVisibility = $_product->getVisibility(); ?>
                    <?php if($productVisibility != 1): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

This works flawlessly when using a block declaration in a CMS page or static block, with the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/pronav_list.phtml"}}
```

Now, I've also slightly modified the widget code but still nothing shows on the frontend. You can see the widget in the backend, and insert it generating this code:

```
{{widget type="cms/list_widget" template="catalog/navigation/pronav_list.phtml" id_path="category/3"}}
```

Again, doesn't produce anything on the frontend. I'm pretty certain this is an issue with the widget code in one of the below files.

List.php - Located at **app/code/local/Ecreation/PNListWidget/Block/**

```
<?php
class Ecreation_PNListWidget_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface {

    protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    protected function _toHtml() {
        $blockHTML = $this -> getLayout() -> createBlock('cms/block') -> toHtml();

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    public function getCategoryID() {
                $idPath = explode('/', $this -> _getData('id_path'));
    }
}
?>
```

widget.xml - Located at **app/code/local/Ecreation/PNListWidget/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <list type="catalog/navigation">
        <name>ProNav Category and Product Navigation List</name>
        <description>Automatically renders 2nd level categories and their products.</description>
        <parameters>
            <id_path translate="label">
                <visible>1</visible>
                <required>1</required>
                <label>Category</label>
                <type>label</type>
                <helper_block>
                    <type>adminhtml/catalog_category_widget_chooser</type>
                    <data>
                        <button translate="open">
                            <open>Select Category...</open>
                        </button>
                    </data>
                </helper_block>
                <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            </id_path>
            <template translate="label">
                <label>Template</label>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <type>select</type>
                <value>catalog/navigation/pronav_list.phtml</value>
                <values>
                    <default translate="label">
                        <value>catalog/navigation/pronav_list.phtml</value>
                        <label>ProNav Sub-Category Navigation List</label>
                    </default>
                </values>
            </template>
        </parameters>
    </list>
</widgets>
```

config.xml - Located at **app/code/local/Ecreation/PNListWidget/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ecreation_PNListWidget>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ecreation_PNListWidget>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I know I'm very close but this is getting frustrating and I need to meet the deadlines for this to be working, so if anyone has any suggestions or can point me in the right direction then that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You said "working properly on frontend" So, what is the result if you used like a widget?

Comment: Has anyone got any pointers on this at all. I really need some advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my .phtml code and it works flawlessly now but I'm still having issues getting the widget to show anything on the frontend?

Comment: I just came accross the following link. Maybe not related your question but check it [Magento Issue Fix – “El is NULL”](http://www.pauldonnellydesigns.com/blog/magento-issue-fix-el-is-null/)

Comment: I've managed to get this all working now. Cheers folks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**app/code/local/Ecreation/PNListWidget/Block**

```
protected function _toHtml() {
    $blockHTML = $this -> getLayout() -> createBlock('cms/block') -> toHtml();
    return parent::_toHtml($blockHTML);
}
```